# Add CSS Styles to Just One HTML element

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I have just started learning about web development and I'm having some issues. In the website that I am currently creating I have a navigation menu. However, I also have other ul and li elements throughout the main content of the web page. I have been trying to get certain styles to apply to just my navigation bar and not the bulleted lists in my content but no matter what I try, I either get the styles on both my navigation and the content or on none. I have looked on google and a lot of different websites, I have tried having the .navigation  and # in front of my styles but nothing seems to be working. I must be doing something wrong somewhere but I have no idea what it could be. If someone could help that'll be wonderful! The following is my navigation barcode:

```
<div id=navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="Home Page.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="About Volleyball.html">About Volleyball</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="Sign-Up.html">Sign-Up</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="Announcements.html">Announcements</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="Links.html">Links</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and these are the styles on my separate css style sheet that I wish to apply to just the above code:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #4da6ff;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 75px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #80bfff;
}
```

Comment: You need to look up id attributes and classes. The [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) CSS tutorial is pretty good.

Comment: https://ilovecoding.org/lessons/css-getting-started-with-css?course=learn-html-css-in-14-days

Answer (score 1):

You can simply select only elements which are children of you navbar by prepending your selectors with `#navbar` which selects the element with the id `navbar` and the selectors after that will only search in its children:

```css
#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #4da6ff;
}

#navbar li {
  float: left;
}

#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 75px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: #80bfff;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Home Page.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="About Volleyball.html">About Volleyball</a></li>
    <li><a href="Sign-Up.html">Sign-Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="Announcements.html">Announcements</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="Links.html">Links</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>No styles applied</li>
  <li>No styles applied</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .css file you can create classes to use across elements.

Try this in the .css file.

```
.hello {
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then try this in your html

```
<h1 class="hello">Hello World</h1>
```

This will apply the style defined in the .css file to the element with the class "hello".

More information about classes can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

Comment: instead of writing a pseudo-tutorial as an answer, better give him a link of a well explained and full tutorial

Comment: So do I just write <div class="navigation" id=navbar"> instead of just <div id=navbar"> and then in my css write .navigation in front of all my style elements?

Comment: I don't think the id is your issue. Your syntax for using it may be. Try 
<div id="navbar">  As for the style elements in your html, put class="navigation" inside the tag. Look at this link for more help and click the "try it yourself button". https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add style to any specific element then you can add CSS code to that specific element like: for tag you can use `p{color:red}` OR by using class: p.my-element{color:red} or using ID: p#{color red}

You are in your initial phase of learning development. So read and write your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [id's](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp) and [classes](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp).

This will allow you to style elements seperately.